# Visual Studio Error Ctrl + Alt + N with Python

Tags: python, visual-studio

I'm new to coding and just started using Visual Studio to learn Python.  In a tutorial video, the professor said that I can hit Ctrl + Alt + N to automatically run my code.  I get the error "[Running] python -u "c:\Users***\Desktop\Test\app.py"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
I am able to run it when I go to my terminal and run through CMD but not when I do the shortcut.  I looked through settings and there wasn't anything I saw that stood out.  Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Add a [mcve] that describes exactly what you're doing and what you're getting

Comment: Is your `python` in the `PATH` environment variable? Also, I'm assuming this has to do with the code runner extension.

Comment: do you know what terminal vs uses when running that command?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Start Search, type in “env”, and choose “Edit the system environment variables”:
2. Click the “Environment Variables…” button
3. Click on Path variable
4. Click on edit button
5. Create a new address, where you have installed python. The default address is C:\Python34
6. Save and exit the window
7. Install Python extension on VScode
8. Restart VScode
9. If problem continues then, open command pallete( CTRL + Shift + p )

9.1. Type Python
9.2. Select python interpreter from the drop down menu